# Linking to a different url using Link of react router dom

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom, link-to

Is there a way to redirect to a different url using Link to?
This is the code I have written:

```
let obj = { key: 'google', title: 'Google link', link: 'www.google.com' }
let obj2 = { key: 'about', title: 'About', link: '/about' }
<Link target={obj.key === 'google' ? '_blank' : ''} to={obj.link}>{obj.title}</Link>
```

Here when I pass obj2 to Link ,it works as expected. From my current page (http://localhost:5000/contactus), it is navigated to http://localhost:5000/contactus page. I also want to redirect to 'www.google.com' but when I do that, it's redirecting to http://localhost:5000/www.google.com. Link to is building upon the parent url. I need it to link to google directly. How do I do it?

Comment: You can not do this by Link tag, you can do -     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"

Comment: if you use 'https:// link' it should work. `let obj = { key: 'google', title: 'Google link', link: 'https://www.google.com' }` because Link is transformed to an <a> tag

Comment: @mgm793 thanks a lot for sharing the link. I am able to do as required with one of the answer posted.